# php: dom replace node by root node from another dom

Tags: php, dom, replace

i need to update a node, from entire node from other document:

Original XML:

```
<a>
<b>Bat</b>
</a>
```

Output i want:

```
<a>
<b>bi</b>
</a>
```

first attempt: replace by documentfragment

```
    $original = "<a>
    <b>Bat</b>
    </a>";
    $replace = "<b>Bi</b>";

    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
    $dom->loadXML($original);

    $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
    $b = $xpath->query('//b')->item(0);

    $fragment = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
    $fragment->appendXML($replace);

    $dom->replaceChild($fragment, $b);

    echo $dom->saveXML();
```

ERROR:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'Not Found
>   Error' in /home/zital/scripts/php/dom.php:17 Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 /home/zital/scripts/php/dom.php(17): DOMNode->replaceChild(Object(DOMDocumentFragment), Object(DOMElement))
>
> ## 1 {main}   thrown in /home/zital/scripts/php/dom.php on line 17

second attempt: replace by importing node

```
$original = "<a>
        <b>Bat</b>
</a>";
$replace = "<b>Bi</b>";

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$dom->loadXML($original);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$b = $xpath->query('//b')->item(0);

$dom2 = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$dom2->loadXML($replace);

$replace = $dom2->documentElement;
$replace = $dom->importNode($replace, true);

$dom->replaceChild($replace, $b);

echo $dom->saveXML();
```

ERROR:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'Not Found
>   Error' in /home/zital/scripts/php/dom.php:42 Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 /home/zital/scripts/php/dom.php(42): DOMNode->replaceChild(Object(DOMElement), Object(DOMElement))
>
> ## 1 {main}   thrown in /home/zital/scripts/php/dom.php on line 42

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you didn't make one more step to get documentElement

```
$dom->documentElement->replaceChild($replace, $b);
```

and the result will be

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<a><b>Bi</b></a>
```

UPD:

In accordance with quite correct Yoshi comment, it is better to write this in such way

```
$b->parentNode->replaceChild($replace, $b);
```

Comment: forks perfect with second attempt :D

Comment: wouldn't `$b->parentNode->replaceChild(...` be a better option?

Comment: @Yoshi yes, of couse. problem of thinking :) . If I wrote myself, then then would write that way. But when I correct someone else's code, trying to preserve it